# how to remove the child elements from selector on CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im trying to make  a horizontal slide list for smaller screens but the issue is that one list has a dropdown inside, and the dropdown list is affected by the parent css atribute!

Ive tried this `not:first-child`  for the first item list but the dropdown still with inline list! here is the code

[image: enter screenshot here]

```css
.tab-nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

.tab-nav-wrapper>ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper>ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -5px !important;
}

.tab-nav-wrapper>ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="navbar-na">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Categorias
      </a>
      <%= render "partials/dropdown" %>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">


      <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-ship" aria-hidden="true"></i> Embarcações'.html_safe,  boats_path, class: "nav-link" %>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">


      <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-search " aria-hidden="true"></i> Serviços'.html_safe,  services_path, class: "nav-link" %>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">

      <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Anuncie conosco'.html_safe,  new_ad_path, class: "nav-link" %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the `li:not(:first-child)` correctly? What about `li:nth-child(2)`?

Comment: @tomashauser ok, so li:nth-child(2) will not affect the first parent and childs of this parent?

Comment: It will only apply to `li`s that are the 2nd child of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear *which*  element you mean that should not be affected by parent element rules, but in general you can use the direct child selector between *all* children elements (not only one), like `.tab-nav-wrapper > ul > li` for css rules to *only* affect the "top-level" `li`  elements of your navigation list, or `.tab-nav-wrapper > ul > li > a` to affect the links inside those list items.

Comment: the elements affected is the     <li class="nav-item dropdown"> parent and his childs   <%= render "partials/dropdown" %> that has another ul

Comment: well, so my answer applies